# want to create a Dayanamic formula creater in PHP

Tags: php

I want to make a dayanamic formula creater in which user saves his formula in a varriable and this varriable will hav to show in other dropdown list.

When we select the formula name from the dropdown list there should be all the fields would be displayed which he had given in the formula nd after that just evaluate the string.

How can I do this in PHP?

example-
formula name= variable field (+ or any operator)variable field(+or any operator)
this formula name would be shown in a other dropdown list nd user select formula from the dropdown list nd there two operator field which we given above should display....

Comment: This question isn't very clear - why not post what you have so far, or a diagram showing what you mean?

Comment: sir i just want to make a matematical formula creator..in which user is to free to save it own formula just like (a+b)/2=average     nd this avaerage will show in a dropdown list when he select that there will two fields a and b are displayed for user for value when he gave value it evaluates the result.

Answer (score 3):

Mohit,

why don't you use eval function? ( very danger function only use if code used in admin side or something like that)

here is simple example of dynamic execution of mathematical formula in PHP.

suppose you have variable $a=25 and $b=15 already bound and you want execute user saved formula [($a+$b)/2].

```
$a=25;
$b=15;
$formula = "($a+$b)/5";
echo eval($formula); // Result will be 20
```

Comment: but i want to make it for all the formulas such as area avearge and any expression in math how we do this